# Triangle numbers that are squares of triangle numbers.

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

What are the triangle numbers the are squares of other triangle numbers? I have found $1^2=1$ and $6^2=36$, but other than these examples I can't find any other triangle numbers that are squares of other triangle numbers, and I used a program to check this idea into the thousands.

Finding triangle numbers that are squares of other triangle numbers corresponds to finding integers $n$ and $k$ such that $n(n+1)/2=[k(k+1)/2]^2$, or such that

> $$2n(n+1)=k^2(k+1)^2 .$$

I believe the only positive integer solutions to this equation are $(1,1)$ and $(3,8)$, but I don't know how to prove it. Are there any others?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Maybe this link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number) can help a bit.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a sketch of a proof that these are all of the positive solutions. It uses some of the machinery of elliptic curves, which in particular is powerful but not elementary. I wasn't able to produce an elementary proof, but I would be grateful to see one.

Comment: I've found two proofs of this in the literature and added citations of them to the end of my answer. The first, due to Ljunggren (1948), is somewhat difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only triangular numbers $T_n = \frac{1}{2} n (n + 1)$ that are squares of triangular numbers are the two you've found, namely $T_1 = 1$ and $T_8 = 36 = 6^2 = T_3^2$.

As you've pointed out, this is equivalent to finding the positive integer solutions to the Diophantine equation
$$2 n (n + 1) = k^2 (k + 1)^2 .$$
(Incidentally, if $(k, n)$ is a solution, so are $(k, - n - 1), (- k - 1, n), (- k - 1, - n - 1)$, so one can derive all of the solutions from the positive ones and the cases where $n = 0$ or $k = 0$.)

I wasn't able to find an elementary solution, and I would be grateful to see one. On the other hand, this solution ties the question with a beautiful topic mathematics and exploits some modern machinery (the main reference for the technique here was published in 1996).

The Maple routine `algcurves:-Weierstrassform()` gives that the coordinate change
$$k = -\frac{18 (y - 4)}{s(x)}, \quad n = \frac{-216 (3 x - 2) (y - 4)}{s(x)^2} + \frac{6 (3 x + 10)}{s(x)} ,$$
where $s(x) := 9 x^2 - 12 x - 68$, is a birational equivalence between the rational quartic curve defined by the Diophantine equation and the [elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) $E$ defined by
$$y^2 = x^3 - \frac{28}{3} x + \frac{160}{27} .$$
This curve has rank $1$ with free generator $G := (-\frac{1}{3}, 3)$, and its torsion subgroup $\operatorname{Tor}(E(\Bbb Q)) \cong \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ with generators $Q_1 := (\frac{8}{3}, 0)$, $Q_2 := (\frac{2}{3}, 0)$ ($Q_1 + Q_2 = (-\frac{10}{3}, 0)$). (Here $+$ refers to the group operation on $E$.) The upshot of this is that every rational point on $E$ has the form $m G + T$ for some integer $m$ and $T \in \operatorname{Tor}(E(\Bbb Q))$, and via the inverse of the first coordinate transformation above these points can be mapped to (all of) the rational solutions to the Diophantine equation; of course, the integer solutions we seek are a subset of these.

There is a powerful machinery for finding all of the integer points on such curves, and it amounts to finding an upper bound $M$ for the coefficient $|m|$ for elements $m G + T$ that correspond to integer solutions. With such a bound in hand, it's then a matter of checking whether each of the finitely many points $m G + T$, $|m| \leq M$ corresponds to an integer solution.

Since our original equation is quartic, our situation is covered by the article of N. Tzanakis cited below. In particular, using the coordinate transformation $k = U, n = (V - 1) / 2$, our equation assumes the form
$$V^2 = 2 U^4 + 4 U^3 + 2 U^2 + 1 ,$$
which is the form required by the method in that article. (NB a priori this transformation may introduce new integral points, but it will not transform integer solutions to noninteger solutions.)

Following the method detailed in the article, which critically involves computing so-called [elliptic logarithms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLogarithm.html) and making reasonable choices for estimates at intermediate steps initially gives an upper bound $M = 8 \cdot 10^{24}$, which gives far too many possibilities to check with even a fast computer. Applying the integral version of the so-called [LLL reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) drastically improves the bound in a single step, to $M \leq 17$, and applying it again improves it to $M \leq 12$ (additional iterations don't seem to improve this bound). At this point, there are only $4 \cdot [2(12) + 1] = 100$ points to check, and a CAS can carry out this procedure quickly. Doing so gives exactly 12 integer solutions $(k, n)$ of our original equation, namely,
\begin{gather}
\mathcal{O} \leftrightarrow ( 0,  0), \quad
- G + Q_2 \leftrightarrow \color{#bf0000}{( 1,  1)}, \quad
  G + Q_1 + Q_2 \leftrightarrow \color{#bf0000}{( 3,  8)},
\end{gather}
and the 9 solutions obtained by applying the mentioned symmetries to these three.

"Making reasonable choices" sweeps under the rug a good deal of computational work, and it's difficult to summarize meaningfully the intermediate steps of the computation. (But I can attempt a gross outline if there's any demand for it.) Perhaps it suffices to say (1) using a CAS is virtually necessary here, and (2) the open-source software SAGE has excellent support for elliptic curve computations and was indispensable in carrying out this computation.

To give a flavor for some of the data used in the calculate of the bound, some invariants of the elliptic curve $E$ used in the mention computations: The affine transformation $x = X - \frac{1}{3}, y = Y$ brings $E$ to the minimal form $Y^2 = X^3 - X^2 - 9 X + 9$. Its discriminant is $\Delta = 2^{12} \cdot 3^2$, its conductor is $f = 192 = 2^6 \cdot 3$ (which lets us quickly identify $E$ as elliptic curve $192\textrm{a}2$ in [John Cremona's tables of curves with small conductor](https://johncremona.github.io/ecdata/)), and its $j$-invariant is $j = \frac{2^6 \cdot 7^3}{3^2}$.

> Tzanakis, N. "Solving elliptic diophantine equations by estimating linear forms in elliptic logarithms. The case of quartic equations." *Acta Arithmetica* **75** (1996), 165-190.

**Edit** After some further searching, it seems that this result appears first in a (French-language) 1946 paper of Ljunggren (I couldn't find any copy online), which gives rather difficult proof by considering the field extension $\Bbb Q[\sqrt[4]{2}]$ of $\Bbb Q$. In 1965 Cassels (I can't find an ungated copy online) gave a simpler proof related to realization of an elliptic curve as a pair of quadrics in $3$-space.

> Cassels, J.W.S., "Integral points on certain elliptic curves." *Proc. London. Math Soc.* **14** (1965), 55-57.
>
> Ljunggren, W., "Solution complète de quelques équations du sixième degré à deux indéterminées." *Arch. Math. Naturv.* **48** (1946), 26-29.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $n$ and $n+1$ are coprime, as are $k$ and $k+1$.  We can have both sides zero if $n=0,-1, k=0,-1$.  Otherwise we must have either $n=k^2,2(n+1)=(k+1)^2$ or $n+1=k^2,2n=(k+1)^2$.  The first gives 
$$n=k^2\\2(n+1)=(k+1)^2\\2k^2+2=k^2+2k+1\\k^2-2k+1=0\\k=1\\n=1$$ while the second gives $$n+1=k^2\\2n=(k+1)^2\\2k^2-2=k^2+2k+1\\k^2-2k-3=0\\k=-1,3\\n=0,8$$
and you have found all the positive solutions.

Comment: You cannot assume that either $n=k^2$, $2(n+1)=(k+1)^2$ or $n+1=k^2$, $2n=(k+1)^2$, because their may be more than one way to factorize the quantity $2n(n+1)$ into two square, coprime factors (what we need for it to be  equal to $k^2(k+1)^2$ ) by moving squares from $(n+1)$ to $2n$ or some variation of that idea.

Answer (score 1):

Above equation shown below:

$2n(n+1)=k^2(k+1)^2$

"OP" gave solutions:  $(n,k)=((8,3),(1,1),(0,0))$

Some more numerical solutions are:  $(n,k)=(1,-2) (-1,-1)$

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I am mainly interested in positive integer solutions to the equation $2n(n+1)=k^2(k+1)^2$, but I just fixed the question.