# Does there exist an integer $b>2$ such that the equation $x^2 = 1+8\cdot b^y$ has at least $2$ integral solutions with $x,y>0$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratics, integers

Let $x,y>0$ be integers. Can we find an integer $b>2$ such that at least two solutions exist of the equation
$$
x^2 = 1+8\cdot b^y.
$$

Initial looking seems to appear that the answer is *no*. For different values of $b$ I've found there are either there are no solutions (ie $b=9$) or exactly one solution (ie $b=10$), but proving the general case I have stalled in being able to find a way to tackle.

**Not looking for full solution, a hint would suffice**

Comment: well, $b = 6$  works

Comment: where did this question come from? Context please

Comment: @Mike its a silly problem that comes from this problem blog post write up I have: [link](https://wjmccann.com/course/unsolvedproblems/sections/theforbiddenmath/). The write up is kinda long though so I left it out here and boiled it down to the relevant problem

Comment: You can rewrite the problem as $|c^y-2d^y|=1$ for some coprime integers $c,d$ such that $b=cd$. Then [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/257131/136794) should help you resolve the $y \geq 3$ case completely. Then only $y=1$ and $y=2$ remains.

Comment: @Sil it is not immediately obvious to me how you could rewrite the equation into that form? Do you mind putting it in an answer

Comment: @wjmccann Added. I am not including complete solution since you did not want that, but basically you take a value of $b$ you get from solving $y=1$ and plug it into equation for $y=2$, then solving the corresponding diophantine equation ([this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2950721/290240) is helpful for that), you get the final result .

Answer (score 2):

I suspect $b=6$  is the only one.

With your $y = 1,$  we get every odd $x$  with $b = \frac{x^2 - 1}{8}$

With your $y = 2,$   we take all $b$   in the sequence $b_{j+2} = 6 b_{j+1}  - b_j, $  that is  $ 6, 35, 204, 1189,...$  as we  then   $x^2 - 8 b^2 = 1.$   Note that the $x_j$  are $17, 99, 577, 336, ...$  and satisfy $x_{j+2} = 6 x_{j+1}  - x_j. $

We can fill in the beginnings  with $b = 0, 1, 6, 35, 204,...$  matching $x = 1, 3, 17, 99, 577,...$

higher exponents: we can quickly deal with $y=3,$   as then we have $x^2 = 1 + w^3$  and $w=0,1$   are the only integer points.

Comment: For your $y=2$ did you get that recurrence relation as the solution to Pell's Equation?

Comment: @wjmccann   right.

Answer (score 2):

*As requested in comments (this is not a full answer).*

Write the equation as
$$
(x-1)(x+1)=8\cdot b^y.
$$
Common factor of both terms on the left divide $x+1-(x-1)=2$ and it's clear they both must be even, hence $\gcd(x-1,x+1)=2$. So $b^y$ must be split into two coprime factors where one divides $x-1$ and other divides $x+1$, this together with two options for $4\mid x-1,2\mid x+1$ or vice versa gives either $x-1=2c^y,x+1=4d^y$, or $x-1=4d^y,x+1=2c^y$, where $c,d$ are coprime and $b=cd$. Subtracting the two equations in each case and dividing by $2$ gives that either $2d^y-c^y=1$ or $c^y-2d^y=1$. Or just compactly $|c^y-2d^y|=1$.

Now to address the last equation for $y \geq 3$ we can use the result in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/257131/136794?_gl=1*ilmf79*_ga*ODQ0NDkwNzM1LjE2OTcwOTc5MjE.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTcwNDM1MDkyOC42ODguMS4xNzA0MzUxMDAwLjAuMC4w) by KConrad (mainly Theorem 1.1 of [https://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/B-Crelle2.pdf](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ebennett/B-Crelle2.pdf)). It implies that for each such $y$ the only solution is given by $c=d=1$, hence $b=1$. This does not meet your condition $b>2$ and so we are left with only $y=1$ and $y=2$ cases.